# Distillation modelling McCable Thiele, Chemical Engineering

Tags: chemical-engineering

I am using an extractive distillation column to seperate ethanol and ethylene glycol. I am trying to find Rmin however its proving difficult as the the top operating line, q-line and bottom operating line do not to intercept the VLE curve. I **have** to use McCabe-Thiele for this before I can proceed onto using Aspen HYSYS. Please help in working out Rmin, thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

extend your q line to equilibrium curve and draw stripping and distillation column line through intersection of q line and equilibrium curve you will get Rmin